# Best way to find a matching value from an array with another set of values using Angular

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I get following array from a service (roles of a logged in user)
roles = ['MM_VIEW', EM_VIEW]

I have a requirement where I need to check whether the user have any one of the below roles and based on that I need to do some logic
MM_VIEW, MM_EDIT, MM_DELETE

So, I was wondering how to proceed with this, to create a enum or directly use OR condition like below

```
    if (user.roles.includes('MM_VIEW') || user.roles.includes('MM_EDIT') || user.roles.includes('MM_DELETE')) {
      this.appImgPIIError.emit(true);
    } else {
      this.appImgPIIError.emit(false);
    }
```

This works, but somehow having hard coded values in my component is not seems a good idea to me. ANy suggestions are welcome. Thanks.

Comment: When you are down voting a question please share the reason, it would be helpful when asking questions next time (if the reason is valid).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some#:%7E:text=The%20some()%20method%20executes,Otherwise%2C%20some()%20returns%20false%20.) method Like below

```
const roles = ['MM_VIEW', 'EM_VIEW'];
const types = ['MM_VIEW', 'MM_EDIT', 'MM_DELETE'];

if( roles.some(r=>types.includes(r)) ){
    event.emit(true);
} else {
    event.emit(false);
}
```